# cakePHP and sql View - pagination taking too long to load?

Tags: sql-server, cakephp, optimization, sql-view

I am currently working on a cakePHP project. I am getting stuck.

I have created a model that uses a MSSQL view as the table:

```
<?php
    class OrderList extends AppModel{
        public $useTable = 'vOrderList';
        public $primaryKey = 'OrderNumber';
        public $order = array(
            "OrderList.OrderNumber"=>"desc"
        );
    }
```

In a sepreate model's controller, I am loading this custom model and trying to paginate the results for the index page:

```
        $this->loadModel("OrderList");
        $this->paginate = array(
            "OrderList" => array(
                'limit'=>10,
                'contain'=>array()
            );
        );
        $results = $this->paginate("OrderList");
```

However, the query is taking way too long!

It takes 8 seconds to load the page!
However, if I open the view table in mssql directly, it only takes a few milliseconds to load.

I can't figure out why!

When I load any other model besides the view I created, it works perfect. It just doesn't work with the custom view table I made

If anyone has any idea, I could use your help!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Alright I figured it out. It was counting the number of entries in vOrderList, which is what was taking most of the time. I changed my OrderList model to count the actual orders table instead.

```
/**
 * Overridden paginate method 
 */
public function paginate($conditions, $fields, $order, $limit, $page = 1,
    $recursive = null, $extra = array()) {
    $recursive = -1;

    return $this->find(
        'all',
        compact('conditions', 'fields', 'order', 'limit', 'page', 'recursive', 'group')
    );
}

/**
 * Overridden paginateCount method
 */
public function paginateCount($conditions = null, $recursive = 0,
                                $extra = array()) {
    $sql =
        "
        SELECT COUNT(*) AS [count] FROM [CustomerOrder] AS [Order] WHERE 1 = 1
        ";
    $this->recursive = $recursive;
    $results = $this->query($sql);
    return count($results);
}
```